# Can Gevent be used in combination with real threads in CPython?

Tags: python, multithreading, gevent, coroutine

just wondering whether gevent coro-thread can work with real threading? perhaps I can write a program with multiple threads and each thread has some coroutines in them?

**edited**

both `gevent.Threading` and CPython threading have their down side.  coroutines cannot utilize multiple CPUs, while CPython Threading performance is limited by the GIL when the number of threads is large.
I'm also working on a pure Python coroutine implementation similar to bluelet (although overhead may be larger than gevent), to add the ability to use coro and threading at the same time.

and I'm just wondering whether gevent or greenlet(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet) can achieve the coop ability with CPython threading.

Comment: I think you could treat the `gevent.Threading` same as `thread.Threading`. These have similitude api. gevent's coro-thread has more effective.

Comment: I understand what u mean and have updated my question

Comment: re your edit: the GIL limits parallelism _all the time_ (i.e. 2 threads) not just when the number of threads is large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gevent 1.0 should support having a Gevent main loop per thread, if that's what you mean.

Also, `gevent.threadpool` allows running tasks in real threads in a gevent-compatible way:

```
threadpool = gevent.threadpool.ThreadPool()
result = threadpool.spawn(some_non_gevent_friendly_thing_such_as_file_io)

result.get()  # or use ThreadPool.apply/apply_e to get the result value immediately
```

You'll find more information about `gevent.threadpool` by looking at https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/src/gevent/threadpool.py (or the doc once the doc for  1.0 becomes available in published/HTML form).